# CloudFlare (Memberful) post requests from Java produce a 403 error

Tags: java, post, cloudflare, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to authenticate users using Memberful from a Spring-Boot application. Per the [Memberful documentation](https://memberful.com/help/integrate/advanced/oauth/#authorization-code-grant), the process is as follows:

1. User logs in at the memberful URL (`https://YOURSITE.memberful.com/oauth?client_id=APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER&response_type=code`)
2. User is redirected to my front end (Vue) with a code in the URL provided by Memberful.
3. The code is passed to my back end server.
4. Back end server sends a post request using `RestTemplate.postForObject(...)` from Spring to `https://YOURSITE.memberful.com/oauth/token` with all required parameters (See snippet below).

At this point an access token payload is expected, but instead a 403 Error is returned.

Here's the full method:

```
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

...


private JSONObject getMemberfulAccessToken(String strCode){
        String strTargetURL = "https://" + memberfulSubDomain + ".memberful.com/oauth/token";


        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        parameters.add("client_id", memberfulApplicationIdentifier);
        parameters.add("client_secret", memberfulClientSecret);
        parameters.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        parameters.add("code", strCode);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(parameters, headers);

        String strAccessToken = restTemplate.postForObject(strTargetURL, entity, String.class);

        return new JSONObject(strAccessToken);
    }
```

And here's the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | [My Site].memberful.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" id='cf_styles-ie-css' href="/cdn-cgi/styles/cf.errors.ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" /><![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">body{margin:0;padding:0}</style>


<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 10]><!--><script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/cf.common.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->



</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="cf-error-details-wrapper">
      <div class="cf-wrapper cf-header cf-error-overview">
        <h1>
          <span class="cf-error-type" data-translate="error">Error</span>
          <span class="cf-error-code">1010</span>
          <small class="heading-ray-id">Ray ID: 515be6c26b80c514 &bull; 2019-09-13 17:39:35 UTC</small>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="cf-subheadline">Access denied</h2>
      </div><!-- /.header -->

      <section></section><!-- spacer -->

      <div class="cf-section cf-wrapper">
        <div class="cf-columns two">
          <div class="cf-column">
            <h2 data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website ([My Site].memberful.com) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (515be6c26b80c514-ua21).</p>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div><!-- /.section -->

      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper">
  <p>
    <span class="cf-footer-item">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong>515be6c26b80c514</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Your IP</span>: 207.200.220.146</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The fix**: Add the JVM option `-Dhttp.agent="[Anything you want as the user agent prefix]"`

**The issue:** Cloudflare's Web Application Firewall prevents requests with the User-Agent header `Java/1.8.0_172` from being received by Memberful.

Cloudflare's [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003014512-4xx-Client-Error#code_403) indicates that if you get a 403 response that is not Cloudflare branded, it's the client's (in my case Memberful's) server that's returning the response.  That being said, I'm not sure if the response I received in response to a POST request could be considered "Cloudflare branded", but at the time I'm writing this Memberful has told me they haven't applied any custom settings for their environment.

Of course there are other ways to set the `User-Agent` header value, but this is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the browser integrity check, which will run even if the WAF is off. Turn off the browser integrity check with a page rule or globally to avoid this issue.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170086-Understanding-the-Cloudflare-Browser-Integrity-Check#:~:text=BIC%20is%20enabled%20by%20default,BIC%20for%20your%20API%20traffic.

Comment: This might help folks who own the site being hosted on Cloudflare, but since I don't own the site in this case, I can't change the setting.