# I receive a 401 error from the server when trying to authenticate a user in my React Native app on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I described my problem in the title.

Some additional info:

**0) When I enable the `Network Inspect` in the React Native Debugger, everything works fine, and I don't have such a problem.**

1) I use expo for my App.

2) I checked the problem on Android emulator (android v. 10) and on real android device (android v. 7) - the result is the same.

3) The problem is not repeated for iOS simulator.

4) I'm trying to make a GET request to remote server `https://.../client/authorize` and pass a JWT with user's email address in the Authorization: Bearer header.

5) I use the `axios` library for requests, but I have the same problem when I use native `fetch`.

6) Expo version is 35.0.0

7) When I disable Network Inspect in the React Native Debugger the problem with authorization on Android devices is back.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: When you receive the response from the /authorize call, are you sure you receive a valid JWT ? Can you console.log it ? If so, is it valid ? Use https://jwt.io/ to validate the JWT and check its contents. It would be good to understand if there is a difference between what iOS Simulator gets and Android Emulator gets.

Comment: What is that https server? Is that yours or is that a third party provider of auth services?

Comment: @TelmoDias yes, jwt is the same for both Android and iOS.

Comment: @DRich this is the server of my customer. I make react-native app and he provide me with backend for it.

Comment: @JustAUser can you try to run the app without React Native Debugger ? Does the problem persist ? Maybe it's something with that specific tool and the Expo version you're using. I normally debug via Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: @TelmoDias sure, I ran the app without React Native Debugger and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to sit down with the owner of the back end to get this figured out.  And it gets more complicated if the server is being hosted by another service.

I had a similar issue not long ago: [CloudFlare (Memberful) post requests from Java produce a 403 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928347/cloudflare-memberful-post-requests-from-java-produce-a-403-error)

Figuring out that, in my case, the agent value was causing the issue was very tricky since I couldn't sit down with the server owner.  What I had to do was use Fiddler and Wireshark to compare the requests that were being sent, identify the differences, and then try them out one-by-one using Advanced REST Client (ARC).

It's tedious, but that's how I had to do it.  If you can sit with the server owner though, they should be able to tell you what they're receiving and what elements of those requests are causing the issue.  They might need to change some configuration on their end.

Hope this helps, and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure, I'm gonna take a sit with the owner of the back end and discuss the issue.
But why is enabling Network Inspect in the React Native Debugger solve the problem?

Comment: I wish I could tell you.  Of course enabling Network Inspect has to change something about what is being sent to the server, but I can't tell you what it is.  If it's like the issue I had, then it could be that Network Inspect intercepts the requests and then re-sends them with a different User-agent value.  Of course, it could re-send them with any other parameter changed as well.  You'll have to take a look at how the requests look different with Network Inspect on vs. off.